# Protobuf defaults vs. "missing required fields" when serializing

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

The SerializeToString() method on a ProtoBuf message containing required fields, that have defaults, always throws the `EncodeError` stating that the message is missing those required fields.  However if I check the value of the fields, all defaults are set.  For example:

```
// mymessage.proto
message MyMessage {
    required int32 val = 1 [default=18];
}
```

Then in python:

```
from mymessage_pb2.py import MyMessage
m = MyMessage()
print m.val # Shows m.val == 18
print m.SerializeToString() # EncodeError
```

On the other hand if I do this:

```
m.val = m.val
print m.SerializeToString() # No Error
```

So clearly, it's just needing each field to get touched despite having a default value on initialization.  For me, one of the major points of having defaults was to only require someone to update the non-default fields (or those fields they need to change), so this set-it-to-itself method is a pretty sorry solution.

Marking the fields as `optional` is not a solution since these fields are legitimately required per our spec.

**UPDATE:** My attempt at a work-around included MergeFrom and CopyFrom, but neither worked.  So I wrote this:

```
def ActuallyInit(obj):
    err = []
    obj.IsInitialized(err)
    for field in err:
        attr = obj.__getattribute__(field)
        try:
            obj.__setattr__(field, attr)
        except:
            ActuallyInit(attr)
```

Then one creates their protobuf object and passes it into `ActuallyInit` which recursively sets each field to itself.  This seems like an ugly hack, so I'm leaving the question below open.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to create the ProtoBuf message instance and "convince" it that every already-initialized-to-default field is in-fact not an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is working as intended. `required` means "the writer must explicitly fill in this field, not use the default". If you want a field where the writer is allowed to leave the field with its default value, then you want `optional`. This is in fact the *only* difference between `required` and `optional`, so there's simply no reason to use `required` with default values. Arguably, the Protobuf compiler should raise an error if a `required` field is defined with a default value, but I didn't think to implement that restriction at the time.

(FWIW, `required` has long been considered [a misfeature](https://capnproto.org/faq.html#how-do-i-make-a-field-required-like-in-protocol-buffers) and has been removed in Protobuf v3.)

Comment: Somehow I came away from the documentation understanding that if I flagged a field as optional, it will not necessarily be part of the message stream.  I definitely did not get the impression that it meant the end user must simply touch the field.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Thomas Well, that's not far off: "touching the field" makes it part of the message stream, otherwise it in fact will not be sent at all, in which case the receiver uses the default value.